# Why unaccent function in Postgres is a stable function? Will the precomputation in column produce the different outputs?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, psql, unaccent

I am optimizing the search query in the Postgres database. The query uses the unaccent function.
I want to create a gin-index to make the search query faster. So I had gone through some articles on faking the stable function as an immutable function using wrapper functions.
I was thinking of creating a new column for precomputed unaccented texts would be good. But I got to know that the unaccent function can produce different outputs.
So what is the preferred way?
Precomputation or using a wrapper function to deceive the program?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this Postgres doc about [unaccent extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html), in my opinion, there are two cases :

**1- Add slug columns to tables :**

**Pros** :

- Slugify concerned table columns at once for the existing DB
- Search by slug.

**Cons** :

- Redundant data, almost if you need to implement multi-criteria searching, in this case you should create a slug(without diacritic signs) for all concerned columns
- Update columns mean update all concerned slug columns
- Create data migrations for the existing database with automated slug creation using [Slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify) for instance.

**2- Use unaccent extension**

**Pros** :

- Don't need to create new db columns
- Stable and trusted extension
- Easy to implement

**Cons** :

- Need data migration to install the extension on PROD ENV
- In case of changing DBMS, you will need to replace the extension